# Azure Pipeline is not able to publish the test report in allure

Tags: azure-devops

I created a azure pipeline to run the automated tests and Included the Allure report. But, test results are not getting published in allure.

[image]

It is failing due to the following reason

[image]

Can some body please let me know what Should I do to fix this issue?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w8j3.png)

Comment: From the error log,  the path couldn't be found Results directory(Report Directory xxxx/ Not found). You need to confrim the file path in the `Generate Allure Report task -> Results directory`

Comment: Once, I push the code, I do not see the folder Allure Results since this folder gets  generated after the execution. By default it already selected the Allure-Results in Results directory.